# Estimating gas of an ERC20 transfer

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, gas

I'd like to estimate the gas of a simple ERC20 transfer between two addresses. The web3.js docs on `estimateGas` are admittedly confusing:

```
// using the callback
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).estimateGas({gas: 5000000}, function(error, gasAmount){
    if(gasAmount == 5000000)
        console.log('Method ran out of gas');
});
```

The `myMethod(123)` is what I find confusing. What is that for? The following is what I'm currently thinking, but I'm getting `TypeError: contract.methods.send is not a function`. What should I substitute for `myMethod(123)`?

```
contract.methods
   .send("0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe")
   .estimateGas({ gas: 60000 }, (error, gasAmount) => {
      return gasAmount;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`const obj = myContract.methods.myMethod(123);`**

---

The variable `obj` is an object in your client-side script which represents a function-call.

In this specific example, it is the function-call `myMethod(123)` on contract `myContract`.

You can use this object for any of the following:

1. `obj.encodeABI()`
2. `obj.call(options)`
3. `obj.send(options)`
4. `obj.estimateGas(options)`

Where `options` is an object with any combination of the following fields:

- `from`
- `gas`
- `gasPrice`
- `value`

If the function does not change the state of the contract (i.e., it is either `pure` or `view`), then `call` is pretty much the only thing that you want to do with it, for example:

```
const retVal = await obj.call({from: x});
```

If the function does change the state of the contract (i.e., it is neither `pure` nor `view`), then all the others (`encodeABI`, `estimateGas` and `send`) are useful, for example:

```
const encodedData = obj.encodeABI();
const requiredGas = await obj.estimateGas({from: x});
const txReceipt = await obj.send({from: x, gas: requiredGas});
```

---

In your specific case, the function-call whose gas consumption you want to estimate would be:

```
myContract.methods.transfer(to, amount)
```

Where:

- `to` is a string which represents an `address` value
- `amount` is a string which represents a `uint256` value

Comment: Thanks. I just don't understand `myMethod(123)`. Is this just a placeholder for another function I'm supposed to call? My inclination is to just call `myContract.methods.estimateGas(options)`.

Comment: @slider: Oh, forgot to refer to your specific request about ERC20-transfer, one sec...

Comment: @slider: Please see updated answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes plenty of sense. In this case, is there any difference between valid `to` addresses, assuming it is simply a wallet address?

Comment: @slider: You're asking if there could be different gas-estimations for different inputs. The answer is yes, depending on what the contract function does with these inputs. In fact, you could get different gas-estimations even for **the same** input. It depends on the current state of your contract. For example, suppose you have `function set(uint _x) public {x = _x;}`, then `myContract.methods.set(5).estimateGas()` would return a large value the first time you call it, and a much smaller value the second time you call it.

Comment: @slider: Similarly, your first transfer to `to` would be more expensive than any subsequent transfer to `to`, because in the first transfer, you'd be changing the balance of `to` from zero to non-zero, and in every following transfer, you'd be changing the balance of `to` from non-zero to non-zero (which costs much less).

Comment: @slider: BTW, specifically for `myContract.methods.transfer(to, amount)`, specifying `{from: x}` inside `estimateGas()` is also essential, because it acts differently depending on the value of `x` (the sender).

Comment: Interesting. I can see the differences in gas from changing the `to` and `amount` arguments in `transfer()`, as well as in `{from:x}`. Thanks a ton, again!